# This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (anonymous android.os.Handler)

Tags: java, android

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("####.0");
        if(msg.what == 1){
            if(!isChart){
                initChart();
                return;
            }
            speedmeter.refresh();
            minVal.setText(df1.format(World.minDB));
            mmVal.setText(df1.format((World.minDB+World.maxDB)/2));
            maxVal.setText(df1.format(World.maxDB));
            curVal.setText(df1.format(World.dbCount));
            updateData(World.dbCount,0);
            if(refresh==1){
                long now=new Date().getTime();
                now=now-currentTime;
                now=now/1000;
                refresh=0;
            }else {
                refresh++;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (anonymous android.os.Handler)

I get an error.
Is there a solution?

Comment: `Handler` is an old low-level solution for communications between threads. Are you *sure* that `Handler` is your best option, compared to more modern solutions (e.g., `LiveData`, RxJava)? The problem is that you might leak whatever object it is that is defining this `Handler`, which feels like an activity or fragment.